# Creating an openFileDialog method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, openfiledialog

My .NET Windows application has multiple instances of being able to open and view text files.  I have no problem getting this to work when I create individual openFileDialogs through my code.  In trying to clean up my code, I created a method, but I am fairly new and am getting a red squiggly.  Can someone please look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

I am trying to call the method as shown here:

```
textBox_ViewFile.Text = LoadFromFile();
```

Then my method is as follows:

```
static string[] LoadFromFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = false;
        openFileDialog1.ShowHelp = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if (openFileDialog1.OpenFile() != null)
                {
                    return (File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case, I am getting a syntax error in VS2010 under "LoadFromFile()" from

```
static string[] LoadFromFile()"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement if either of your `if` statements are `false`

```
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.OpenFile() != null)
            {
                return (File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName));
            }
            // missing
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            // missing
            return null;
        }
    }
    // missing
    return null;
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you Brandon.  Also had to add a third "return null;" after the final IF.

Answer (score 1):

`textBox_ViewFile.Text` is a `string`. Your function returns an array (`string[]`). You need to make the function return a single `string`.

```
return string.Join('\n', File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName));
```

Or:

```
return File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: I tried all of the combinations mentioned here and I am still getting a syntax error under the "return..." options.  I copied exactly what you had.

Comment: What is the error exactly? Hover over the squiggly line and let us know.. all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Jeagr Then your issue is what BrandonCuff has said below. But also, once you've fixed this issue, my answer will also help you (that would also have been a compiler error).

Comment: Yes, your issue helped also.  Thank you Simon!